# How does this Old English text (from the dedication of the book “The White Horse King”) translate in Modern English?

Tags: translation, old-english

The dedication of the book [The White Horse King](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6905753-the-white-horse-king) (Merkle, 2009) contains the following:

> Hwa Þeos, Þe gesihÞ swa swa se morgen
>   Fæger swa se mona
>   Beorht swa se sunne
>   Torhtmod swa se scildweall.

I have not travelled to 9th century England ever since my time machine broke, so my Old English is a bit rusty, but I can identify the obvious, such as *morgen* = "morning", *mona* = "moon", *sunne* = "sun", and *scildweall* = "shield wall". How would a full translation read?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It roughly translates to:

> What this, thee sight so as the morning 
>   Beautiful as the moon 
>   Bright as the sun 
>   Glorious as the shield.

> Hwa Þeos, Þe gesihÞ swa swa se morgen 
>   Fæger swa se mona 
>   Beorht swa se sunne 
>   Torhtmod swa se scildweall.

- hwa (pronoun) who/what
- þéos (Pronoun) this
- þé (pronoun) thee
- gesihþ (nominative) 1. sight; vision 2. sight of a person or object; singular (se gesihþ)
- sé (definite article/pronoun)- the/that
- swá/swá - so or as
- morgen (noun) morning
- Fæger (adjective) beautiful; good-looking; attractive
- mōna (noun) - moon
- Beorht (strong adjective) (West Saxon) bright; clear
- sunne (noun) - sun
- Torhtmod - golorious/noble
- scildweall (noun) sheild - wall; wall of shields; the shields held by a line of soldiers

Comment: "How soft your fields so green
Can whisper tales of gore
Of how we calmed the tides of war
We are your overlords"